# Привязка PictureBox к Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Как поместить на элемент Panel уже существующий на форме другой элемент управления, например PictureBox?

До этого делал так: создавал Panel из Toolbox, потом перетаскивал из Toolbox нужные элементы на внутреннюю область Panel.

А если, нужно добавить на панель уже существующий составной элемент, не заново же его каждый раз создавать. Должен быть элегантный и одновременно простой способ..

Comment: В коде не пробовали?

Comment: вы хотите собрать на элемент типа `Panel` нужные кнопочки и прочее а потом такой составной элемент добавлять куда вам нужно?